# how to change selection based on another selection with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my html
how to change selection form based on this:

```
<select id="myclass">
<option value="one">Form one</option>
<option value="two">Form two</option>
</select>
```

I chose "Form one" it show me only  select id="one" or it 
I chose "Form two" it show me only  select id="two"

```
<select id="one">
<option value="one1">one1</option>
<option value="one2">one2</option>
</select>

<select id="two">
<option value="two1">two1</option>
<option value="two2">two2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there any jQuery code to go along with what you've attempted so far?

Comment: So add a change event and show/hide the element. Seems basic. What do you not know how to do? What did you try?

Comment: epascarello  - i did not know how to do

Comment: Sphinx - i did not need Populate Selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by Jquery as follows:

```
$('#myclass').change(function(){
       $('#one, #two').hide();
       $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('#myclass').change(function(){
   $('#one').hide();
   $('#two').hide();
   $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```